# problema de primos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Amigos necesito ayuda porfa con este codigo donde me puedo estar equivocando?
siempre me dice que el primo mayor esta en las posiciones 0:

'''Leer 10 enteros, almacenarlos en una lista y determinar en qué posiciónes de la lista está el mayor número primo leído'''

```
try:

    lista=[]
    lista2=[]
    lista3=[]
    aumento=0

    for i in range(10):
        numero=int(input("Digite un numero entero: "))
        lista.append(numero)

    for l in range(len(lista)):
        primo=lista[l]
        aumento=0

        for k in range (1,primo+1):
            if (primo%k)==0:
                aumento+=1

        if aumento==2:
            lista2.append(primo)        

    print(lista2)

    mayor=lista2[0]

    for m in range(len(lista2)):
        if lista2[m]>mayor:
            mayor=lista2[m]

    for s in range(len(lista2)):
        if lista2[s]==mayor:
            lista3.append(s)

    print(lista3)

except ValueError:
    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está acá:

```
 for s in range(len(lista2)):
        if lista2[s]==mayor:
            lista3.append(s)
```

Porque tú no tienes que revisar la lista de los números primos sino la lista de los números ingresados, entonces, quedaría algo así:

```
 for s in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[s]==mayor:
            lista3.append(s)
```

Además! Te recomiendo un método más fácil para comprobar si un número es primo, sólo tienes que probar los números primos hasta la raíz cuadrada de dicho número inclusive, por ejemplo:

Si tienes 67 y quieres saber si es primo, no pruebas desde 1 a 67 todos los números y vas dividiendo, simplemente calculas la raíz cuadrada de 67, que es 8.18, luego, pruebas del 2 a la raíz cuadrada inclusive y listo. Si es divisible por algún número primo entre 2 y 8, entonces, ya no es primo.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo por la aclaracion pero me podrias decir porque hay que revisar la lista normal cuando lo mas logico seria revisar la lista donde estan los primos?? espero me puedas explicar y gracias de nuevo

Comment: Porque lo que tú quieres saber es justamente, dada una lista de números enteros, mostrar en qué posición está el mayor de ellos. Sí, está bien que almacenes los números primos, pero como no todos van hacerlo, le estás quitando el orden que tenían en la lista de enteros original, entonces, por esa razón tienes que comprobar la lista 1 y no la lista de primos.

Comment: no encuentro fallas en tu logica.png jajajaja mucahs gracias brother me quedo claro